# Directory does not exist - Parameter name: directoryVirtualPath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, stack-trace, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 RC.

- If a create a blank "hello world MVC 4.5 project"
- I Downgrade it to 4.0 so it is compatible with my host (Arvixe)
- I publish it to the host.

And then i get this error message, i can find any information on it online.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Directory does not exist.
Parameter name: directoryVirtualPath

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Directory does not exist.
Parameter name: directoryVirtualPath

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: Directory does not exist.
Parameter name: directoryVirtualPath]
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.IncludeDirectory(String directoryVirtualPath, String searchPattern, Boolean searchSubdirectories) +357
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.Include(String[] virtualPaths) +287
   IconBench.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) +75
   IconBench.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +128

[HttpException (0x80004005): Directory does not exist.
Parameter name: directoryVirtualPath]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9160125
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +131
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +253

[HttpException (0x80004005): Directory does not exist.
Parameter name: directoryVirtualPath]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9079228
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237
```

What does it mean ?

**Code as requested^^**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("Hello world");
    }
}
```

thats the only code i added.

**application_start code**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**FilterConfig**

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

**BundleConfig**

```
 public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure will do, but it's just a test.

Comment: can you post the code inside application_start ?

Comment: @BjarkeCK thanks.are you sure all of files included in RegisterBundles exist in you'r application's directory?

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili Interesting, i maybe excluded the Content folder when i published :), will try to delete all the bundles and publish again!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

it seems that this error originates from "not including desired files in your application's directory" or uploading your code in a directory that is not configured as virtual directory , 
or even in incorrect directory.

Comment: I think you are very right :) Will test it, and be back in a min

Comment: Well i think that resolved the issue, but now it's a new one: http:**temp.iconbench.com/

Comment: check if this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses

Comment: Allright, now i'm at least one step closer. Thank you alot for your help, learned alot.

Answer (score 6):

This post is similar to [Directory does not exist. Parameter name: directoryVirtualPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317384/directory-does-not-exist-parameter-name-directoryvirtualpath)

The answer helped me debug.  Apparently, there are missing folders on the target server.  My application worked fine locally, but when I published, several `script` sub-directories did not get published.  When I manually FTP'd them up, the app worked fine!

Comment: This was my issue too. Visual Studio doesn't seem to Publish empty directories by default, even though the application uses them and they are Included in the Project.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the information here.

I often bundle all file in a folder like so: `"~/Content/js/angular/modules/*.js",`
And this works great as long as the folder exists.

The issue is, if that folder is empty when you publish it will not be published and will result in the above exception. So now i either put an empty.txt or something of the sort of add the folder manually if i want them to remain empty for now.

Comment: Ah, that saved me hours :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check if you have dll in bin folder and also the dll exist in the GAC

remove dll from GAC

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was "Content" folder which I forgot to upload to the server

Answer (score -4):

Create directory "/Content/themes/base"